# How to import MySql table into a targeted database in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am using hadoop version 2.6.0 & sqoop version 1.4.5. I have successfully imported a SQL table- ***tblSystem*** into hive using the following sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip_Address:port_no/MySQL_database_name --username user --password passwd --table tblSystem -m 1 --hive-import
```

However, I noticed that this command imports the SQL table into the 'default' database in hive. What is the command to target the import to a particular hive database, say, ***myHiveImport*** ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Import a MySQL table into Hive:**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldatabase --table mysqltablename --username mysqlusername --password mysqlpassword --hive-import --hive-table hivedatabase.hivetablename --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse
```

Changes to be made:

`mysqldatabase` -- Your mysql database name from which the table is to be imported to hive.

`mysqltablename` -- Your mysql table name to be imported

`mysqlusername` and `mysqlpassword` -- mysql username and password respectively.

`hivedatabase` -- Your hive database name

`hivetablename` -- Table name to be created in hive.

Try this:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip_Address:port_no/MySQL_database_name --username user --password passwd --table tblSystem -m 1 --hive-import --hive-table myHiveImport.tblSystem --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse
```

Change `--warehouse-dir` location to point to your HDFS hive storage path.